# HIbernate Can't delete Entity with foreign key. Foreign key gets set to null

Tags: java, mysql, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa

This question has been asked in many forms here but none of the solutions seem to work for me. I'm trying to delete the parent entity and I want all of the child entities to also be deleted.

My entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item", catalog = "myshchema")
public class Item implements java.io.Serializable {

@JoinColumn(name = "item_id", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<ItemCategory> categories;

/* Getters and Setters and other fields*/
}
```

Table for Item:

```
CREATE TABLE `item` (
`item_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`store_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `item_id_UNIQUE` (`item_id`),
KEY `FK_ITEM_STORE_ID_idx` (`store_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_ITEM_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `store`   (`store_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=84 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And my other entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item_category", catalog = "myschema")
@IdClass(ItemCategoryIndex.class)
public class ItemCategory implements java.io.Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "category_id", unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Integer categoryId;
@Id
private Store store;
@Id
private Item item;
@Id
private String categoryName;

/* Getters and Setters */
}
```

Table for ItemCategory:

```
CREATE TABLE `item_category` (
`category_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`store_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`category_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `category_id_UNIQUE` (`category_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `IDX_UNIQUE_STORE_CATEGORY`     (`store_id`,`item_id`,`category_name`) USING BTREE,
KEY `FK_CATEGORY_STORE_ID_idx` (`store_id`),
KEY `FK_ITEM_CATEGORY_ID_idx` (`item_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_CATEGORY_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES     `store` (`store_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `FK_ITEM_CATEGORY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `item`     (`item_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=162 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I try to delete the item like this:

```
Item item = entityManager.find(Item.class, idList.get(i));
entityManager.remove(item);
```

My logs show that Hibernate is trying to set the primary key for ItemCategory to null:

```
Hibernate: update myschema.item_category set item_id=null where item_id=?
ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions 146 - Column 'item_id' cannot be null
```

I even tried looping through the child records and deleting them manually, but Hibernate still issues this update to null query.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Mind updating your question with the two table structures? It looks like there is also something wrong with your entity mapping and annotations. "mappedBy" is supposed to be used in the non-owner of the relationship but you used it in the owner of the relationship, which has a `@joinColumn`.

Comment: Hi Minjun Yu.  I've updated my question with the table definitions.  I removed mappedBy from the owner side also.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### I have to break your problem down to two parts

#### First - let's talk about your database schema design.

According to your schema, `item` and `item_category` has a **one-to-many** relationship meaning an item can **have/be-assigned-to** different categories but different items cannot **have/be-assigned-to** the same category.

That is totally fine **if it is indeed your business requirement**, I mention it because it does not make sense to me and this circumstance rarely happens.

If what you want is that a category can have multiple items and vice versa, `item`and `item_category` must be a **many-to-many** relationship. There should be a **join table** additionally.

#### Second - let's say the schema don't change

`ItemCategory` is the owner of the relationship because it has a foreign key `item_id` refering to `item` table. So the ItemCategoy should look **roughly** like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item_category")
public class ItemCategory {

  @Id
  private Integer categoryId;

  private Store store;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="item_id", /*cascade = ...*/)
  private Item item;

  private String categoryName;

  /* Getters and Setters */
}
```

Your `Item` entity will be **roughly** like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item", catalog = "myshchema")
public class Item implements java.io.Serializable {

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy="item")
  private Set<ItemCategory> categories; //`mappedBy`used here because this entity is not the owner of the relationship according to what mentioned above

  /* Getters and Setters and other fields*/
}
```

To remove all the child entities(`ItemCategory`) from `Item` , simply

`em.remove(item);`

The `orphanRemoval` is `true`, deleting the parent, the children will be deleted as well.

Comment: The problem was that I had *.hbm.xml files for my Entities and Hibernate was ignoring my annotated classes.  After I cleaned that up, I was able to get it working with your suggestion.  Regarding my database design, categories are more like tags, so an Item can have multiple categories.  Thank you for taking the time to look at this.

Comment: You are welcome. Like I said, you design supports item having multiple categories/tags, but one category/tag **cannot** be applied to different items. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Yup, that's how it's intended.

Answer (score 4):

In Hibernate, you need to decide who is owning the relationship. If you have the parent side (ItemCategory) owning the relationship, you will find insertion/deletion of Item+ ItemCategory will involve update of item_id in ItemCategory table (which is what I observed from your exception). In most case it is not preferable. We usually let the children own the relationship. This is done by using mappedBy

(pseudo-code)

```
class Item {
  //...

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "item", cascade=ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
  private Set<ItemCategory> categories;
}

class ItemCategory {
  //...

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="item_id")
  Item item;
}
```

The trick here is mappedBy

Comment: why is category a child? My logic tells me it should be a parent class...