# Spring boot, Hibernate, mySql application does not honour foreign key constraint

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm developing Spring boot, Hibernate, mySql application.
I'm new to Spring, Hibernate and have problem with foreign keys.

Here are my environment and fragments of code I use with my application:

Environment:

```
  Debian GNU/Linux 9.4 x86_64 (stretch)
  JDK jdk-8u162-linux-x64
  Spring Tool Suite ver: 3.9.4
  Spring boot ver: 2.0.0.RELEASE
  Hibernate and mySql versons are set by Spring boot
```

Code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="city",uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"name"},name="UK_City_name")})
public class City implements Serializable {
  [...]
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Size(min=NAME_SIZE_MIN,max=NAME_SIZE_MAX)
  @Column(name="name",length=NAME_LENGTH,nullable=false)
  private String name;

  @Column(name="colleges")
  @OneToMany
  @JoinColumn(name="city_id",foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="FK_college_city_id"))
  private Set<College> colleges = new HashSet<>();
  [...]
}

@Entity
@Table(name="college",uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"name","city_id"},name="UK_College_name_city_id")})
public class College implements Serializable {
  [...]
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Size(min=NAME_SIZE_MIN,max=NAME_SIZE_MAX)
  @Column(name="name",length=NAME_LENGTH,nullable=false)
  private String name;

  @ManyToOne
  private City city;
  [...]
}

@Controller
@Transactional
public class CityController {
  @Autowired
  CityDao cityDao;
  [...]
  @RequestMapping({"/cityListRemoveItem"})
  public String removeCityHandler(HttpServletRequest request,Model model,@RequestParam(value="id") Long id) {
    City city = null;
    if (id!=null)
      city = cityDao.findCity(id);

    if (city!=null)
      cityDao.remove(city);

    return "redirect:/admin/cityList";
  }
}

@Transactional
@Repository
public class CityDao {
  @Autowired
  private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
  [...]
  public City findCity(Long id) {
    try {
      String qu = "Select c from "+City.class.getName()+" c Where c.id = :id";

      Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
      Query<City> hibernateQu = session.createQuery(qu,City.class);
      hibernateQu.setParameter("id",id);

      return (City)hibernateQu.getSingleResult();
    }
    catch (NoResultException ex) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  @Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
  public void remove(City city) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    try {
      session.delete(city);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  [...]
}
```

I create database using org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.
The content of the exportScript.sql file is:

```
create table city (id bigint not null auto_increment,name varchar(15) not null,primary key (id));
create table college (id bigint not null auto_increment,name varchar(91) not null,city_id bigint,primary key (id));
alter table city add constraint UK_City_name unique (name);
alter table college add constraint UK_College_name_city_id unique (name,city_id);
alter table college add constraint FK_college_city_id foreign key (city_id) references city (id);
[...]
```

For testing I add the following records to the application's database:

```
Table "City":
Id  name
-----------
 1  'city1'
 2  'city2'

Table "College":
Id  name       city_id
----------------------
 1  'college1'       1
 2  'college2'       2
```

If I open application's database in SquirrelSQL and try to delete record 'city1' from table "city" by running query:

```
delete from city where id = 1;
```

I get an error:

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails...
```

It is fine as it should be, and it is what I want my application to do.

But it does't.
When I try to delete the same record from the application, Hibernate creates the following queries:

```
update college set city_id=null where city_id=?
delete from city where id=?
```

and removes 'city1' record from the table "city" without any exception.

What is wrong with my code?
Why application's session.delete(city) does not throw "foreign key violation" kind exception?

Thank you, Mikhail.

Comment: Possible duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40353605/hibernate-cant-delete-entity-with-foreign-key-foreign-key-gets-set-to-null